# Deploy vb Application Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I have a vb application that relies heavily on Crystal Report. The reports run fine while in development mode but once the executable is generated it doesnt open the reports anymore and raises an exception saying Load Report Failed ( with a bunch of CrystalDecision references that it can't find).

- **Development Environment:**

Visual Studio 2017 
Win10 64bit
Crystal Report (forVS and Runtime) 13.0.21

- **Target:**

win7 on 32bit
.NET 4.5
Crystal Report Runtime 13.0.5

We tried including the Crystal references that might be causing the problem when publishing the project but that didnt resolve the problem.

Also, the project was initially developped in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 with CR 13.0.5 and apparently at some point they did some additional dev in VS2017 and so had to migrate the reports to a supported version of CR.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply include the missing references for Crystal Reports.  You need to install the Crystal Reports Redistributable (Runtime) for your version on the target system.

Comment: We did that as well but it turns out some of the test machines had a bunch of missing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package. We ended up adding those and removing all the unnecessary crystal references and matching the CR Runtime installed on target machines to the one used in the dev environment (13.0.021)